# NSNotificationCenter & unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, unrecognized-selector

I have bunch of 'item' objects that include a picture of the item. When my app runs it loads the image of the item from a url. When it is loaded it posts a notification to NSNotificationCenter with the ID of the image.

I have a subclass of UIImageView that has a pointer to the item and listens for notifications with that item ID. When the item's image is loaded from the url the imageView updates the image to the item's image.

However, sometimes (but not 100% of the time) something weird happens and I get an exception thrown:

```
-[__NSCFType imageLoaded:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I think ARC is for some reason releasing an object too early. But I don't use weak pointers because I had a bad experience once. Here is some code:

```
//Inside my Item object
-(void)loadItemImage{
    ConnectionManager *conman = [[ConnectionManager alloc] init];
    [conman getImageWithURL:self.imageURL inBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSString *error, id image) {
        if (image){
            self.image = image;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i", self.pk] object:nil]; //exception is thrown here.
        }else{
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

//inside my ImageView class (subclass of UIImageView)
-(void)imageLoaded:(id)sender{
    self.image = item.image;
}
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that if the object was somehow released wouldn't it then not be listening for the notification? It seems that if the object is listening for a notification then it could call the selector method.

Comment: You have to remove observer for notifications in the dealloc method of the object that is the observer for this given notification. The problem is in the class that is added as an observer for this notification.

Comment: I think that fixed it. It's hard to say because it didn't always break. But after three tests I think it is working.

Comment: Also, this is dangerous: "I don't use weak pointers because I had a bad experience once" - if you are never using weak references you probably have strong reference cycles in your app.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts I'm seconding Aaron Brager, you should learn how to use weak and strong references correctly. ARC doesn't mean you can't create memory leaks or cycles. And if you have everything retained (strong) then you will eventually hit a retain cycle somewhere. Make sure you understand why and where to use weak references!

Comment: Ok, ok, you convinced me..

Comment: One other thing. A golden rule I try to follow for Observers. Add them in `viewWillAppear:`/`viewDidAppear:` and remove the observers when viewControllers is not active. Not active in the sense, if the observer alters GUI elements, remove them in the `viewWillDisappear:`/`viewDidDisappear`, and if they alter data, remove them in `dealloc`. This is to add robustness if your viewController pushes/presents another viewController. In that case, you viewController stays in the view hierarchy, but might not necessarily need the observers at those times.